# Grpc requests failing when python client used inside flask

Tags: python, flask, grpc, grpc-python

I have a flask app that needs to make a request to a grpc server when a request is made to the flask endpoint.

```
@main.route("/someroute", methods=["POST"])
def some_function():
    # Do something here
    make_grpc_request(somedata)
    return create_response(data=None, message="Something happened")


def make_grpc_request(somedata):
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:30001')
    stub = some_proto_pb2_grpc.SomeServiceStub(channel)
    request = some_proto_pb2.SomeRequest(id=1)
    response = stub.SomeFunction(request)
    logger.info(response)
```

But I keep getting an error `InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with: StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE failed to connect to all addresses`

Just putting the client code inside a normal `.py` file works fine, and making the request inside BloomRPC works fine too so it couldn't be a server issue.

***Is this something to do with how flask works and I'm just missing something?***

I have also tried using https://github.com/public/sonora without any success like this:

```
with sonora.client.insecure_web_channel("localhost:30001") as channel:
    stub = some_proto_pb2_grpc.SomeServiceStub(channel)
    request = some_proto_pb2.SomeRequest(id=1)
    response = stub.SomeFunction(request)
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  core-profile: #This is where the grpc requests are sent to
    container_name: core-profile
    build:
      context: ./app/profile/
      target: local
    volumes:
      - ./app/profile/:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./app/profile/database.env
      - ./app/profile/jwt.env
      - ./app/profile/oauth2-dev.env
    environment:
      - APP_PORT=50051
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      - POSTGRES_HOST=core-profile-db
    ports:
      - 30001:50051
    expose:
      - 50051
    depends_on:
      - core-profile-db

  core-profile-db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 54321:5432
    env_file:
      - ./app/profile/database.env

  app-flask-server-db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    expose:
      - 5433
    ports:
      - 54333:5433
    env_file:
      - ./app/flask-server/.env

  flask-server:
    build:
      context: ./app/flask-server/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - ./app/flask-server:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./app/flask-server/.env
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=docker
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - app-flask-server-db

volumes:
  app-flask-server-db:
    name: app-flask-server-db
```

Comment: How are you running the services?

Comment: The grpc services are running inside a docker container using the same docker-compose.yml file as the flask server.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the `docker-compose.yml` file in your question. I suspect (!?) that you're trying to access the gRPC server as `localhost` but it's been given a different name by Compose DNS (the service name).

Comment: Thanks Daz, I've added the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Ok, so your Python app should reference the gRPC service as `core-profile:50051`

Comment: The host name is the Compose service `core-profile` and, because the Python service is also within the Compose network, it must use `50051`. `localhost:30001` is how you'd access it from the Compose host.

Comment: Okay it works now. How stupid of me. You can add that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python app (service) should reference the gRPC service as `core-profile:50051`.

The host name is the Compose service `core-profile` and, because the Python service is also within the Compose network, it must use `50051`.

`localhost:30001` is how you'd access it from the Compose host